# python truncating inputs from shell to specific number

Tags: linux, python-3.x, shell

When I am trying to provide a large input, it is truncating to a specific number.

eg. If I input around 50k-100k inputs(156 repeated number of times), its truncates to 1023. But when I provide input around 200k(shown below), it truncates to 1187.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    iplist = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    print("len of exp: ",len(iplist))
```

1) provide very large input: 
eg. below is 1686 numbers input , but if you run the above code, it says length is : 1187:

Seems there is some character limit in shell as if I change a few numbers from 3 digit to 2 digit, or 1 digit, this length increases

```
0 82 180 55 168 41 179 59 139 71 6 12 135 139 73 157 4 74 195 60 45 28 67 136 58 55 22 60 33 84 48 185 118 29 41 86 22 172 145 114 43 103 126 130 43 152 87 199 26 34 59 24 63 79 160 73 86 134 133 71 18 182 57 89 163 98 175 137 70 73 3 113 176 130 43 19 34 83 170 12 117 30 36 132 61 197 5 99 131 91 171 102 25 28 143 188 126 118 77 148 143 81 61 120 163 56 91 149 91 62 161 161 44 198 93 57 195 51 156 78 142 127 132 119 107 75 59 33 146 136 133 89 169 146 161 84 3 5 33 46 67 195 7 63 193 53 120 140 56 28 170 150 156 103 69 63 178 128 49 124 64 182 166 186 129 79 70 84 84 104 82 103 51 42 166 44 95 38 136 103 67 106 53 175 161 122 190 140 50 39 16 66 174 134 52 55 14 123 91 98 179 173 2 30 15 120 26 62 159 114 165 178 172 18 153 134 140 143 26 142 135 42 9 61 129 61 68 143 136 159 193 67 132 195 49 100 68 27 114 27 141 80 157 66 50 110 0 191 5 26 133 92 20 142 105 149 156 173 44 44 84 38 112 169 185 113 69 53 141 183 32 34 15 189 100 66 51 52 9 57 78 94 101 51 37 159 152 145 132 197 189 17 187 53 138 172 167 159 26 108 142 58 94 110 48 195 176 51 47 137 108 78 31 162 129 20 121 33 165 5 182 107 174 169 112 112 142 79 71 120 139 166 178 34 76 178 181 4 30 28 93 90 58 124 4 139 145 125 173 62 131 155 121 57 125 34 170 19 65 41 139 5 159 69 191 187 0 172 143 182 152 36 24 163 161 29 102 58 154 27 120 37 183 194 95 60 28 17 79 93 10 170 50 170 39 193 157 191 117 101 173 22 89 198 185 50 27 87 108 133 115 181 123 50 175 170 62 155 187 141 0 197 63 3 119 102 196 29 46 66 82 19 88 171 169 73 22 196 112 82 82 179 15 157 181 142 127 43 97 66 136 50 15 199 53 135 54 1 116 100 67 198 119 155 121 89 180 95 37 93 178 71 24 145 28 6 88 107 1 137 173 138 139 141 137 192 28 191 146 144 43 13 94 163 169 15 4 101 111 193 146 41 17 171 138 197 129 178 105 130 116 30 68 7 171 158 152 151 149 98 95 193 111 141 108 32 157 64 134 20 57 80 61 26 3 199 24 132 178 129 63 46 111 83 53 35 41 5 186 143 55 34 88 119 175 148 151 132 12 37 104 21 70 165 48 25 117 72 158 47 153 173 93 16 56 98 51 50 56 38 193 63 24 81 182 199 29 134 84 193 123 188 166 145 106 14 171 23 38 129 22 143 54 67 160 62 165 11 112 173 1 105 37 25 138 19 25 119 105 61 64 181 49 31 126 155 45 97 130 36 178 152 179 32 19 139 47 137 151 159 62 152 17 51 130 107 23 155 27 128 168 91 109 17 74 188 125 120 85 7 108 16 160 87 48 131 27 95 20 130 7 35 34 24 86 164 131 109 71 110 190 39 154 99 9 28 39 134 100 125 93 8 141 5 96 141 137 75 189 109 157 196 144 143 172 31 60 103 92 83 166 82 75 120 134 84 148 173 170 1 98 63 9 191 69 57 133 158 84 74 19 41 70 164 137 42 147 197 97 39 80 63 122 155 135 56 191 36 29 113 37 80 129 46 71 150 56 156 108 140 30 127 134 100 43 71 94 190 68 144 182 100 159 104 8 95 112 151 131 141 65 168 21 146 166 45 96 22 1 156 163 184 35 97 36 79 120 131 21 140 27 3 192 186 59 0 81 171 152 12 113 169 132 86 115 99 83 163 121 37 119 36 21 154 85 57 185 157 140 7 97 167 162 90 154 22 42 35 193 146 0 58 115 84 97 182 183 180 145 57 17 64 45 190 171 83 48 156 40 188 163 138 156 78 180 62 100 22 49 45 169 49 104 36 134 153 171 69 133 116 78 103 133 124 93 104 7 93 12 199 82 128 137 190 6 69 52 106 92 101 151 13 103 7 1 189 160 172 10 46 89 89 101 174 165 194 30 124 40 42 123 74 170 13 64 176 82 68 34 126 169 186 139 24 193 141 13 106 113 24 152 154 65 53 128 182 199 158 106 39 1 181 113 123 194 129 100 29 197 134 155 119 72 95 143 18 188 109 124 101 85 76 8 102 81 136 84 32 47 142 72 0 123 137 123 70 67 175 99 16 110 6 135 134 101 31 152 89 92 76 143 129 104 151 31 185 39 115 170 38 57 42 190 132 131 114 154 150 41 53 167 103 60 54 38 113 37 190 155 81 19 98 10 123 1 41 61 192 108 31 31 117 25 21 50 108 87 4 59 129 10 178 184 22 32 22 135 22 165 42 103 184 92 66 59 93 107 72 86 168 55 69 85 80 42 87 189 130 92 0 11 54 178 195 76 162 170 163 184 135 6 40 119 98 106 130 192 165 3 30 133 58 51 171 91 93 58 32 175 150 32 138 4 162 86 32 124 56 196 61 191 2 53 62 52 111 192 44 76 147 26 162 6 29 133 49 75 191 81 50 94 65 141 50 179 27 83 103 83 31 116 26 185 121 88 37 32 32 34 61 180 12 175 138 42 108 139 117 51 172 119 97 37 12 148 168 39 183 23 74 14 140 100 151 61 140 188 46 125 22 107 57 35 34 147 29 142 86 98 145 58 17 43 47 30 143 15 21 126 38 96 92 130 148 43 144 41 183 190 118 158 49 127 145 83 74 174 177 160 72 74 170 41 117 17 23 60 32 45 138 22 93 182 153 193 177 97 186 161 39 104 119 40 183 64 123 57 38 52 17 62 126 187 103 196 156 79 8 140 76 147 163 169 81 68 114 59 117 101 20 156 157 139 196 141 155 71 150 145 123 168 7 1 107 62 197 16 141 158 156 17 105 119 138 138 187 53 197 56 106 17 12 15 108 160 108 63 31 59 8 106 179 167 60 38 182 9 54 75 167 11 45 24 82 183 163 22 188 160 78 46 178 43 14 38 3 122 54 187 181 14 45 112 182 105 151 116 115 5 191 34 168 36 59 51 172 22 25 112 182 103 111 112 146 125 151 102 199 157 89 133 171 134 45 153 192 196 21 59 154 13 93 74 1 152 125 125 126 150 190 61 6 101 173 104 178 76 6 177 33 95 110 5 182 156 110 174 104 132 185 10 97 78 85 50 183 162 176 109 65 166 170 71 19 96 127 197 124 134 126 110 29 37 67 163 145 129 137 1 61 122 164 110 153 1 161 136 163 89 197 180 7 120 51 26 16 131 175 92 65 101 2 46 90 69 10 187 199 99 141 12 174 57 75 127 58 36 15 21 125 164 2 84 84 5 110 52 136 37 145 153 90 99 0 181 121 10 120 72 61 13 36 35 70 111 114 128 99 81 102 176 46 104 60 130 61 122 135 150 159 32 103 50 83 55 183 4 65 103 28 79 69 65 114 139 128 181 20 28 62 122 4 108 178 17 191 191 139 78 141 99 110 197 149 193 52 132 150 70 187 178 149 56 43 63 148 172 44 168 152 59 42 108 167 172 125 110 163 65 188 105 164 50 54 65 44 106 149 146 176 88 124 125 145 120 141 45 44 137 165 196 196 159 56 116 131 182 178 94 47 167 151 163 169 5 180 165 112 129 111 40 17 36 166 114 108 59 111 152 196 76 100 145 35 156 61 166 90 39 13 89 158 164 4 128 170 184 45 34 65 157 74 35 145 192 149 53 51 13 157 0 41 9 145 29 117 6 195 8 197 160 97 108 125 102 188
```

Could you please explain this? If this is `python`/`shell` issue and how can I overcome it ? I am trying to run a hackerrank test case which is having very large input around 200000. But I am not able to run that testcase in my terminal due to this limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation specific to the shell, rather than Python. Just to bring your attention to some things, here is what you can do in the future:

1. Initial hint - if you paste this and attempt to add characters in a modern shell you see you can't!
2. paste your input into a file, preferably with one item on a line.
3. Add a few debug lines

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       iplist = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
       with open('test.dat','w') as fd:
           fd.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in iplist))
       print("len of exp: ",len(iplist),iplist[0],iplist[-1])
   ```

   So now you have a quick reference to the first and last read items in the list, and a file containing the entire read list. Immediately you see the last item is 188 - suspicious.
4. If you pasted your input into a file in (1) you can easily check line 1187 is indeed 188.
5. Using the test file above you can count characters in the input actually read using a tool such as `wc -c test.dat`.
6. I get 4095, which is suspiciously close to 4096 = 4 KiB (often written as kB)

This is a clear hint for a "system" level limitation, likely your shell, limiting the amount of characters you are allowed to put in a single line. This specific limitation is pretty standard, and you can probably find somewhere the documentation for the limit.

Jack's answer is the way to go here - this is no way to read large input.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that there is a character limit in shell commands which it looks like you are hitting with that much of data on the command line.

I would refer you to the man page for that but you will not need to know it precisely hopefully ever.

The reason for that is you'll never want to put yourself in this position and to avoid that, all you need to do is save your input to a file, and change your python to open that file and read it line by line.  Many examples on SO how to do something like that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good answer regarding the specific limit and what is limiting it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365338/364079